# PHP Oracle get ID based on another column value contains with array

Tags: php

How to get `PROFILEID` based on `ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS` contains check?

Data table

```
PROFILEID   PROFILE_NAME        ACTIVE  DATEADDED               ADDEDBY LOCATIONID_FK   ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS
PF0001      Normal Working Day  Y       9/30/2017 5:53:39 PM    US0001  LC0001          192.168.183.205, 192.168.183.28
PF0004      Ramadhan            N       10/12/2017 10:38:02 AM  US0001  LC0003  
PF0002      Ramadhan            N       9/30/2017 5:55:50 PM    US0001  LC0001          192.168.183.205, 192.168.183.28
PF0003      Normal Working Day  Y       10/3/2017 5:23:05 PM    US0001  LC0003          192.168.184.20, 192.168.184.15
```

-

```
$allowedIP = array();
$profileID = array();

$qProfile = oci_parse($c1, "
    SELECT P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS, P.PROFILEID, P.PROFILE_NAME, P.LOCATIONID_FK, L.LOCATIONID, L.LOCATIONNAME FROM WA_BT_TBL_PROFILE P, WA_GA_TBL_LOCATIONS L WHERE P.LOCATIONID_FK = L.LOCATIONID AND P.ACTIVE = 'Y'
");
oci_execute($qProfile);
while($dProfile = oci_fetch_array($qProfile))
{
    $allowedIP = array_merge($allowedIP, array_map('trim', explode(',', $dProfile['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS'])));
    $profileID = array_merge($profileID, array_map('trim', explode(',', $dProfile['PROFILEID'])));
}
```

Try to print_r($allowedIP)

```
Array ( [0] => 192.168.183.205 [1] => 192.168.183.28 [2] => 192.168.184.20 [3] => 192.168.184.15 )
```

Try to print($profileID)

```
Array ( [0] => PF0001 [1] => PF0003 ) <-- What I want it show based on IP Address contains, means only 1 will show
```

PHP

```
//to check if current IP Address contains with database
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allowedIP))
{
    //then get the `PROFILEID`
}
```

Assume my IP Address is: 192.168.183.28
As you can see on Data table, I should get PROFILEID PF0001 with ACTIVE = 'Y'

Comment: Is this supposed to be a local application? It doesn't make any sense to use ip here, as you know they keep changing ;)

Comment: @B001 Yes, only for local IP. Any advice?

Comment: Sorry but imo it is a fail using IP adresses...

Comment: @B001 what do you mean?

Comment: If this is supposed to be a permission based application then IPs are wrong here. You can use user/group credentials/permissions instead